# update on duplicate key in php script

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've created a unique index on my table for page_id and display_id but i'm having issues with PHP syntax on doing a duplicate key update call.

This is the sql query in my php script:

```
$assignPage = "
INSERT INTO display_to_page (page_id, display_id)
VALUES ( '".$pageID."', '".$displayID."')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
active = 1
";
```

But it's not passing the syntax at the ON DUPLICATE KEY part.

I just want to say (insert this,but if the page_id/display_id key exists then update by setting the active column to 1)

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: You're doing plenty wrong. This is not how to build a query. Use prepared statements or you will have all sorts of problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string concatenation had an error, so I simplified it.

```
$assignPage = "INSERT INTO display_to_page (page_id, display_id)
                VALUES ( '$pageID', '$displayID')
                ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE active = 1";
```

> You should also use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's rather than value concatenation.

Comment: Thanks so I actually don't need the SET? Because it seemed to work without it

Comment: Yea, I realised my mistake there and remove it from my answer

Comment: @miken32 Hmm nore do i now :?